# How to get firebase to display last 5 searches result to an HTML div?

Tags: javascript, firebase

My goal is to use firebase to store the last 5 search results in a div with class databasesnap in my HTML. But I'm getting some errors such as: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined And the search results are not posting in the div.

```
var config = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyCzaNmYb94HQPR70d6Omy5kP1d0kw5NLkc",
  authDomain: "eventtraveler-69f59.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://eventtraveler-69f59.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "eventtraveler-69f59",
  storageBucket: "eventtraveler-69f59.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "73086206077"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

var database = firebase.database();

var location ;
var inDate ;
var outDate;
$("#add-event").on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

var location = $("location-input").val().trim();
var inDate = moment($("start-date-input").val().trim(), "MM/DD/YYYY").format("X");
var outDate = moment($("end-date-input").val().trim(), "MM/DD/YYYY").format("X");
var databasesnap = database.ref().set({
  location: location,
  inDate: inDate,
  outDate: outDate
})

});

database.ref().limitToLast(5).on("value", function(snapshot) {

var appendToDiv = $("<p>").append(
  $("<p>").text(location),
  $("<p>").text(inDate),
  $("<p>").text(outDate),
  );


$(".databasesnap").append(appendToDiv); 

})
```

Comment: some input value is undefined

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It wouldn't let me put the entire code in the editor. So which values are undefined?

Comment: check error line.... probably any of these `var location = $("location-input").val().trim();
var inDate = moment($("start-date-input").val().trim(), "MM/DD/YYYY").format("X");
var outDate = moment($("end-date-input").val().trim(), "MM/DD/YYYY").format("X");
`